# decrypt values in sqlite database and view them on datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

am new to wpf and am having a bit of trouble on how to decrypt an a encrypted values in my db to view on a datagrid , i have been searching for a solution for almost 2 days and  only came up with this code

```
//private static String Encrypt(string Text)
//private static String Decrypt(string Text)
private void refresh_datagrid()
{

//create temp directory

var tempdir = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(),Guid.NewGuid().ToString()));
Directory.CreateDirectory(tempdir);

//create temp db with same table and details same as on original db

        SQLiteConnection.CreateFile(tempdir+"tempdb.sqlite;security=true;");
        var con1 = new SQLiteConnection("Data 
        Source="+tempdir+"\\tempdb.sqlite;");
        con1.Open();
        con1.ChangePassword(defaultpassword);
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE acc (nam STRING, pas STRING)";
        SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, con1);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();

//open a connection to encrypted db

        using (var con2 = new SQLiteConnection("DataSource="+db_path+";security=true;"))
        { 
            con2.Open();
            con2.ChangePassword(defaultpassword);

            SQLiteCommand cmd = con2.CreateCommand();

            cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM acc ";

//read encrypted strings to decrypt it then pass them to tempdb

            SQLiteDataReader reader;
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
           while(reader.Read())
            {
                SQLiteCommand cmdc = con1.CreateCommand();
                cmdc.CommandText = "INSERT INTO  acc (nam,pas) VALUES (@username ,@password )";

                cmdc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", Decrypt(reader["nam"].ToString()));
                cmdc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", Decrypt(reader["pas"].ToString()));

                cmdc.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

//view tempdb data on datagrid

            SQLiteDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd.CommandText, con1);
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            dataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
            control.ItemsSource = dataTable.AsDataView();

            con1.Close();
             con2.Close();

//remove tempdir and tempdb 

            Directory.Delete(tempdir,true);
        }
}
```

it works but this is just a simplified code.
on my full code i have more tables with 6 more details and 120 accounts 
and when i try to view them on my datagrid the app hangs for 3-4 seconds i went around this problem with [backgroundworker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)
but still not satisfied with the delay i need a better way to handle this any help is appreciated.

ps: sorry about any wrong grammar or spelling EN is not my home language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Try to add logs in between lines to find out the bottle neck
2. Read all the records to memory from encrypted db first instead of writing while reading
3. How many rows are there in the db? Do you join all of the 6 tables in your query? Consider sql tuning

Comment: ok i just want to thank you . after reading your answer i almost solve the problem 1- i just finished running performance profiler after a few pause and  and capturing the call stack each time 2 function calls show up every stack first one is the overloaded **Encryption(Double value) function** and the **Decryption(Double value)** so i stopped these 2 functions and the process went from 3-4 seconds to 1-0.7   seconds and cpu usage to 40-70% i suppose it's an issue with my encryption algorithm [the bottle neck]